# Re-Arrange columns based on Column names which are DATE

Tags: c#-4.0, datatable

I need to re-arrange/sort the columns of a DataTable based on the names of the column. Then names/caption of the column is date, i.e, I need to re-arrange/sort the columns based on the Date. Consider the below sample table:

| Column1 | 29-Jan-2015 | 25-Jan-2015 | 1-Feb-2015 | 25-Dec-2014 | IsActive |

|  Val1   |   Val1      |   Val1      |   Val1     |  Val1        |   1     |

|  Val2   |   Val2      |   Val2      |   Val2     |  Val2        |   1     |

I need to sort the columns only after the first column and before teh IsActive column. i.e., my expected output is:

| Column1 | 25-Dec-2014 | 25-Jan-2015 | 29-Jan-201 | 1-Feb-2015 | IsActive |

|  Val1   |   Val1      |   Val1      |   Val1     |  Val1        |   1     |

|  Val2   |   Val2      |   Val2      |   Val2     |  Val2        |   1     |

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Got it. Thanks John Saunders.